# How to pass more than one argument in response entity

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I can save two entity on one post request all done but how can i pass more than one argument in `ResponseEntity<T>` while returning in rest-api. I am new in `rest-api`.

Here down is my code for Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/coursebook", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Course> saveCourseBook(@RequestBody Course course, @RequestBody Book book)
{
    try {
        Course saveCourse = this.pojoService.addCourseBook(course);
        Book saveBook = this.pojoService.addBookAuthor(book);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(saveCourse); // Here i want to add `saveBook` also for json response.
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: What additional information do you intend to pass to the `ResponseEntity`?

Comment: I can already declare this i want to pass two object in response entity parameter. one is `saveCourse ` and second is `saveBook `.

Comment: you can have a generic class or a separate class for response.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved your query :)

Answer (score 3):

The response class that you are trying to send back can have any number of fields. You can have a generic response class like this.

`Response`

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Response<T,K> {

    private T courseResponse;
    private K bookResponse;

}
```

Once this is done, you can modify the controller as

```
@RequestMapping(value="/coursebook", method= RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Response<Course, Book>> saveCourseBook(@RequestBody Course course, @RequestBody Book book)
{
    try {
        Course saveCourse = this.pojoService.addCourseBook(course);
        Book saveBook = this.pojoService.addBookAuthor(book);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new Response<>(
                saveCourse,
                saveBook
        ));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
    }
}
```

Or, you can get in a `CourseResponseDTO` class to do the same.

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CourseResponseDTO {

    private Course course;
    private Book book;

}
```

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/coursebook", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<CourseResponseDTO> saveCourseBook(@RequestBody Course course, @RequestBody Book book)
    {
        try {
            Course saveCourse = this.pojoService.addCourseBook(course);
            Book saveBook = this.pojoService.addBookAuthor(book);

            return ResponseEntity.ok(new CourseResponseDTO(
                    saveCourse,
                    saveBook
            ));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
        }
    }
```

Comment: second one worked for me thank you very much